# BigQuery Allow Large Results doesn't work when

Tags: google-bigquery, rstudio-server

I am trying to retrieve table from BigQuery into Rstudio Server with the following:

```
project <- "my-project"
sql <- 'SELECT * FROM [my-project:dataset.table]'
data <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf)
```

> Error: Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults

I've checked "Allow Large Results" when configuring the table in the browser, still get the same error.

Used the following as well but without any success.

```
bq query --allow_large_results --destination_table=dataset.table1 "select x, y, z from dataset.table"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you get this error, you have to set `allowLargeResults` to true and specify a destination table. You can find the explanation in the link provided by the error message:

> Normally, queries have a maximum response size. If you plan to run a
>   query that might return larger results, you can set allowLargeResults
>   to true in your job configuration. **Configuring large results requires
>   you to specify a destination table**. You incur storage charges for the
>   destination table.

In your case, I guess you are using the `bigrquery` package. If so, the function `query_exec` has an optional argument called `destination_table`, whose description is:

> (optional) destination table for large queries,
>   either as a string in the format used by BigQuery, or as a list with
>   project_id, dataset_id, and table_id entries

In summary, using this argument you can provide a destination table (and implicitly set `allowLargeResults` to true), so you should use:

```
project <- "my-project"
sql <- 'SELECT * FROM [my-project:dataset.table]'
data <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf,
                   destination_table = "my-project:dataset.newtable")
```

Just keep in mind that you will create a new table called *newtable* in your dataset.